# Read TCP message with CAPL

Tags: tcp, capl

I am trying to read a message via TCP.

```
variables
{
  dword serverIpAddress = 0x0101A8C0;  
  dword serverPort    = 502;           
  dword clientIpAddress = 0x0201A8C0;  
  dword size = 2;
  int varRead_AI;
  char Read_AI_receive[1024];
  long Read_AI_TCP;
  long result_Read_AI;
  
  byte Read_AI[12]= {0,0,0,0,0,6,1,3,0,1,0,0};
}


TcpSend(gConnectionSocket,Read_AI,elcount(Read_AI)); // send the request   
// void OnTcpReceive( dword socket, long result, dword address, dword port, char buffer[], dword size)
void OnTcpReceive(dword gConnectionSocket, long result_Read_AI, dword serverIpAddress, dword serverPort, char Read_AI_receive[], dword size)
{
   write("result_Read_AI: %d",result_Read_AI);
}
```

Which values do I have to give the function and does the function returns the result (in the varible result) for every TCP message which comes in?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You want to know, what the signature of `OnTcpReceive` is? Which problems (error messages/behavior) do you observe?

Comment: I am not sure which variables I have to give the function in order to return the content of the message. So the content of the message should be written in the `buffer` right? But this is not the case. And I know that there should be content in the message as I tested it (it is a Modbus message) with a tool; I sent `Tx: 00 1B 00 00 00 06 01 03 00 01 00 01` and got `Rx: 00 1B 00 00 00 05 01 03 02 31 E3` as a answer. So `31 E3` is the hex-value.

Comment: You do not _give variables to the function_. CANoe calls `OnTcpReceive` and you use the input parameters for whatever you want. In your case, there might be a clash between the global variables you define and the names of the parameters of `OnTcpReceive`. There is no need for you to define any variables.

Comment: @M. Spiller So I don't need to define the variables form `void OnTcpReceive( dword socket, long result, dword address, dword port, char buffer[], dword size)` like the result and buffer[] and they CANoe will define them?

Comment: These are no variables, but parameters to a function.
At runtime CANoe will e.g. execute `OnTcpReceive(1, 2, 0x123, 80, 'abcd', 4)`.
You have to program the logic inside of `OnTcpReceive` which will be called by CANoe. How the parameters are named is not important. Also parameters and (global) variables have no connection at all.

Comment: So now (when I don't define the variables) I get as result and size: 0 which according to Vector means, that the socket was closed by the communication peer. How can I avoid this @M.Spiller?

Comment: How could anybody - but you - know? The information you have posted here is just a simple code snippet, showing a dummy implementation of `OnTcpReceive`. There is zero relevant information about your use case. What is your _communication peer_ and how does it behave, e.g. when does it close the communication? How does the rest of your code look like? How and when do you call `TcpReceive`? Etc. I don't think that stackoverflow is the right place for getting help debugging your CANoe configuration. Contacting Vector Support or a (paid) consultant will get you better results.